# How to check using Twilio IncomingCall is Disconnect in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-api

How to check using Twilio IncomingCall is Disconnected.

I got bellow logs when incoming call disconnected (Like Missed Call Type). but all log are inbuilt Lib's logs so i can't catch or use.

```
06-25 09:55:20.293 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/PJSIP: 09:55:20.293  dlg0xb9ce6504  ........Transaction tsx0xba71b874 state changed to Completed
06-25 09:55:20.294 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/Call(native): tw_call_get already exists
06-25 09:55:20.294 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/UserAgent(native): got on_call_state for call id 0
06-25 09:55:20.295 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/Call(native): tw_call_get already exists
06-25 09:55:20.295 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/UserAgent(native): ... forwarding to java
06-25 09:55:20.298 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/MediaManager: playing sound DISCONNECT as id 2
06-25 09:55:20.298 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxI/Connection: Connection disconnected successfully.
06-25 09:55:20.298 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxD/UserAgent(native): cinfo.state ... 487
06-25 09:55:20.298 2037-2186/com.reach.xxxI/PJSIP: 09:55:20.298  pjsua_media.c  ..........Call 0: deinitializing media..
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Connection Interface Reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/connection#overview) allows you to track [Connection State](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/Connection.State) and interact with the [ConnectionListener](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/connectionlistener#onDisconnected_Connection_) where you will want to explicitly track `onDisconnected` method.

In logs it seems as though this works as expected so without seeing your code, I'm not sure what exactly could be the problem.